# Why does printing a character variable with %d give a negative value in c?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, placeholder, signed, shift

I tried the following piece of code, expecting the output to be positive 64:

```
char val = 0x80; 
printf("%d",val>>1);
```

My understanding of what happens is(please correct me if i'm wrong as i probably am):

1. Referring to the ASCII table, there is no mapping of 0x80 to any character so i assume this is stored as an unsigned integer.
2. This is represented as 1000 0000 in bitwise format, so a right shift of 1 would result in 0100 0000
3. When printed as an integer value, this will then show as positive 64.

**However** it shows -64.

In contrast:

```
char val = 0x40; 
printf("%d",val>>1);
```

gives positive 32.

Is the value implicitly converted to a signed integer in the first case and not in the second?

Comment: if `char` is signed in your implementation, the value `(int)(char)0x80` is more like binary `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000`

Comment: `so i assume this is stored as an unsigned integer.` - Most likely, neither `char` nor the implicit `int` you're using are unsigned. If you want unsigned behaviour, say so explicitly.

Comment: The type of `char` does not change according to what you have stored in it. If `char` is signed, then so is `0x80` which is `-128`. And if `char` is signed, then `val>>1` is either undefined or implemention defined (can't remember which), but going back to the output `-64` then your `char` cannot be unsigned.

Comment: The `char` type is promoted to `int` when passed to a variadic function like `printf()`. It is also promoted to `int` to perform the shift. Since a signed `int` can hold all possible values of `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`, the converted value is type `int` regardless of the signedness of `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C implementation uses an eight-bit signed `char`. (The C standard permits `char` to be signed or unsigned.) In `char val = 0x80;`, a `char` cannot represent the value you initialize it with, 128. In this case, the value 128 is converted to `char` which, per C 2018 6.3.1.3 3, yields either an implementation-defined value or a trap. Your implementation likely produces −128. (This is a common result because 128 in binary is 10000000, and converting an out-of-range result to an eight-bit two’s complement integer often simply reinterprets the low eight bits of the value as eight-bit two’s complement. In two’s complement, 10000000 represents −128.)

So `val>>1` asks to shift −128 right one bit. Per C 2018 6.5.7 5, shifting a negative value right yields an implementation defined value. Producing −64 is a common result.

(In detail, in `val>>1`, `val` is automatically promoted from `char` to `int`. It has the same value, −128. However, with a 32-bit `int`, it would then be represented as 11111111111111111111111110000000 instead of 10000000. Then shifting right “arithmetically,” which propagates the sign bit, yields 11111111111111111111111111000000, which is −64, the result you go. Some C implementations might shift right “logically,” which sets the sign bit to zero, yielding 01111111111111111111111111000000. In this case, the `printf` would show “2147483584”, which is 2<sup>31</sup>−64).

Whether ASCII has any character with code 0x80 is irrelevant. The C rules apply to the values involved, regardless of what character encoding scheme is used.

Answer (score 0):

Right shift of the signed integer is implementation-defined. In most modern systems signed integers are two's complement and the shift will be translated by the compiler to the **arithmetic** shift.

[image]

after the shift the binary value of `val` is `0xc0` which is `-64` in the two's complement encoding.

The `val` is converted first to the signed integer then passed to the function. If you put some effort into your question and add a few more lines to your code you would discover it yourself.

```
int main(void)
{
    char c = 0x80;

    printf("%d\n", c >> 1);
    printf("%x\n", c >> 1);
    printf("%hhd\n", c >> 1);
    printf("%hhx\n", c >> 1);

    c >>= 1;

    printf("%d\n", c);
    printf("%x\n", c);
    printf("%hhd\n",c);
    printf("%hhx\n",c);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YsaGos

You can also see if the MSB bit is 0 arithmetic shift behaves exactly as the binary shift, thus `0x40 >> 1 == 0x20`